# Apply state before trying to react for a saga pattern in Commanded

Tags: elixir, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing, commanded

When implementing a saga pattern with the `Commanded.ProcessManagers.ProcessManager` module in the event sourcing/CQRS framework Commanded I ran into a problem.

In an invoicing context, I needed to implement a mass creation mechanism for invoices. This mass creation is realized both as an aggregate and a saga. The aggregate allows starting and finishing the mass creation. The saga reacts to the "mass creation started" event by issuing commands to create the invoices and keeping their IDs in the saga state. Afterwards the saga tracks the status of the invoice creation by listening to the success or failure events of the invoice instances it commanded into existence. As soon as every invoice instance reported either success or failure, the saga should issue the command to stop the mass creation.

For this, it would be helpful to track each invoice instance with its current status: `in progress`, `created` or `failed`. I tried implementing this in the `apply` callback and in principle this works nicely.

The problem now is, that the `apply` callback is always called after the `handle` callback. Therefore the saga state is updated after the saga is supposed to react. This seems counter-intuitive and because of this, the state available within the `handle` callback cannot be used to properly react.

In my opinion, the saga pattern is in a lot of ways an inversion of the aggregate pattern. While it is useful to first process a command into a domain event and then apply this domain event into the state in case of an aggregate, I think that in case of a saga, the domain event, which is a documentation of something that already happened, should be applied to the state before trying to react to it.

Now my question would be: Is there a way to configure Commanded to first `apply` and then `handle` for the `Commanded.ProcessManagers.ProcessManager` module? Or is this acutally a bug and needs to be fixed in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoking the `apply/2` callback after `handle/2` is by design, it's not possible to configure Commanded to behave differently.

I agree with your reasoning that it makes more sense to apply the event to the process manager's state before attempting to handle the event to produce any commands. This seems like a worthwhile change to make to Commanded which can be tracked by the issue you've already raised ([#176](https://github.com/commanded/commanded/issues/176)).

In the meantime you can implement your process manager (saga) as follows:

```
defmodule InvoicingProcessManager do
  use Commanded.ProcessManagers.ProcessManager,
    name: __MODULE__,
    router: InvoicingRouter

  defstruct [
    :batch_uuid,
    pending_invoice_ids: MapSet.new()
  ]

  def interested?(%InvoiceBatchStarted{batch_uuid: batch_uuid}), do: {:start, batch_uuid}
  def interested?(%InvoiceCreated{batch_uuid: batch_uuid}), do: {:continue, batch_uuid}
  def interested?(%InvoiceFailed{batch_uuid: batch_uuid}), do: {:continue, batch_uuid}
  def interested?(%InvoiceBatchStopped{batch_uuid: batch_uuid}), do: {:stop, batch_uuid}
  def interested?(_event), do: false

  # Event handlers

  def handle(%InvoicingSaga{}, %InvoiceBatchStarted{} = started) do
    %InvoiceBatchStarted{batch_uuid: batch_uuid, invoice_ids: invoice_ids} = started

    Enum.map(invoice_ids, fn invoice_id ->
      %CreateInvoice{
        invoice_id: invoice_id,
        batch_uuid: batch_uuid
      }
    end)
  end

  def handle(%InvoicingSaga{}, %InvoiceCreated{invoice_id: invoice_id}),
    do: attempt_stop_batch(pm, invoice_id)

  def handle(%InvoicingSaga{}, %InvoiceFailed{invoice_id: invoice_id}),
    do: attempt_stop_batch(pm, invoice_id)

  ## State mutators

  def apply(%InvoicingSaga{} = pm, %InvoiceBatchStarted{} = started) do
    %InvoiceBatchStarted{batch_uuid: batch_uuid, invoice_ids: invoice_ids} = started

    %InvoicingSaga{
      transfer
      | batch_uuid: batch_uuid,
        pending_invoice_ids: MapSet.new(invoice_ids)
    }
  end

  def apply(%InvoicingSaga{} = pm, %InvoiceCreated{invoice_id: invoice_id}) do
    %InvoicingSaga{pm | pending_invoice_ids: invoice_completed(pm, invoice_id)}
  end

  def apply(%InvoicingSaga{} = pm, %InvoiceFailed{invoice_id: invoice_id}) do
    %InvoicingSaga{pm | pending_invoice_ids: invoice_completed(pm, invoice_id)}
  end

  ## Private helpers

  def attempt_stop_batch(%InvoicingSaga{batch_uuid: batch_uuid} = pm, invoice_id) do
    pending_invoices = invoice_completed(pm, invoice_id)

    case empty?(pending_invoices) do
      true -> %StopInvoiceBatch{batch_uuid: batch_uuid}
      false -> []
    end
  end

  defp invoice_completed(%InvoicingSaga{pending_invoice_ids: pending_invoice_ids}, invoice_id) do
    MapSet.delete(pending_invoice_ids, invoice_id)
  end

  defp empty?(map_set, empty \\ MapSet.new())
  defp empty?(%MapSet{} = empty, %MapSet{} = empty), do: true
  defp empty?(%MapSet{}, %MapSet{}), do: false
end
```